# Firestore - how to track number of read and write operations

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I notice that Firestore Billing is based on stored data, downloaded data, and also on number of read and write operations.

Is there a way to see how many read or write operations are being called, hopefully tracked by day?

As far as I can tell, in the Billing section, it just tells me the number of read operations I am paying for - but I don't have any details on that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer.  Go to Firebase Console > Database > Cloud Firestore > Usage.

Comment: Is there any way to track the realtime numbers too?